# unix command to grep text from server and write it to a file in unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

the below i have to do using a script which will be there on unix box server.
I wanted to grep text(eg.`Some_ID=123456`) from log files present in log folder of my server.
and want to c create and write that data into another text file which will be also present on the same server.
 i got the below code from google. i am starting to learn unix.

```
mylogfilename="/path/mybiglogfilename"

my_id="000000000000000"
cat -n "${mylogfilename}" | grep "${my_id}" | awk '{print $1,$2}'| while read mylineno mydata
do
      mylineno_before=`expr ${mylineno} - 1`
      mylineno_after=`expr ${mylineno} + 1`
      sed -n "${mylineno_before},${mylineno_after} p" ${mylogfilename}
done
```

can any one help me out with the same.

Comment: this looks like a lot of pipes for something that `awk` might handle alone. What about providing a sample input and desired output?

Comment: In fact it looks like you reinvented `grep -C1 "$my_id" "$mylogfilename"`

Comment: Doing two passes where the first obtains the line numbers of the lines you already found in order to print them in a second pass is generally a catastrophic antipattern. The site where you found this code should probably not be used for learning proper shell  scripting practices.